# use DISTINCT on multible rows and columns

Tags: php, mysql

This is my url: [link](http://www.stamps-as-a-gift.com/index.php)

I have used the following code:

```
<?php include "config.php";

//select a database to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db("projecten_test",$dbhandle) 
or die("Could not select examples");

// Get specific data from the "products" table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT cat1,cat2,cat3,cat4 FROM products") 
or die(mysql_error());  ?>

<?php



echo "<br /><table border='1'>";
echo "<tr> <th>cat1</th><th>cat2</th><th>cat3</th><th>cat4</th></tr>";

// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
// Print out the contents of each row into a table

echo "<tr><td>"; 
echo "<a href=\"#\">".$row['cat1']."</a>";
echo "</td><td>"; 
echo "<a href=\"#\">".$row['cat2']."</a>";
echo "</td><td>"; 
echo "<a href=\"#\">".$row['cat3']."</a>";
echo "</td><td>"; 
echo "<a href=\"#\">".$row['cat4']."</a>";
echo "</td></tr>"; 

} 

echo "</table>";
?>
```

I used DISTINCT because I do not want to see duplicate values in these columns.

In my case I would like to see:

cat1 column shows one "Travel" and one "Holland"
cat2 column shows one "Famous People" and one "water"

so on..

I have tried with union and concat_group but I cant get this to work properly. The way it is displayed now ( in this table ) is a must - i must be able to move each cat row ( or maybe div later on ) to another spot.

Thanks a lot..:)

Comment: How does your data look? Also, what does `"i must be able to move each cat row ( or maybe div later on ) to another spot."` mean?

Comment: `select distinct` applies to the ENTIRE set of fields requested. it's not `distinct(field1), all field2, all field 3, etc...`. it's `distinct(field1, field2, field3, ...)`

Comment: @MarcB You sure about that? `SELECT DISTINCT c1, c2, c3 FROM t1` as per http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html

Comment: @OP: Try adding a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Fred-ii- marc is still correct. it is the distinct combination of all three / n columns.. just like adding a group by.. `distinct(field1, field2, field3, ...)`

Comment: @JohnRuddell MySQL.com doesn't state a bracketed method. I figured if there was, they would, wouldn't they?

Comment: @JohnRuddell (and OP and whoever's reading this) Doing `DISTINCT (col1, col2)` gave me `Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in...` 

Doing `DISTINCT col1, col2` works but gives me duplicate records on `col2` using `order by`. Therefore, if OP wants to use what Marc suggested, will need to add a `GROUP BY` clause. Edit: Scratch that, even using `DISTINCT (col1, col2)` with a GROUP BY errored out.

Comment: @Strawberry Seems like somebody knows something we don't.

Comment: @Fred-ii- no DISTINCT isn't a function.. but the parenthesis were just used to show where the distinct is applied

Comment: @Strawberry I know!!! It is for visually seeing where the DISTINCT is applied. just so there isn't confusion on it applying to only the first column.. but I didn't think fred would think it was a function lol

Comment: @JohnRuddell I misunderstood what Marc meant then (just laid out weirdly, a bit misleading); my mistake. However, I think the OP will still need a GROUP BY clause, since doing a few tests revealed that, while having duplicate entries inside both of the columns in one of my tables.

Comment: @Fred-ii- it is a little confusing, I was looking at all of marcs comment so it made more sense at the time... if you look at the first part of marcs comment its clearer with the `distinct(field1), all field2, all field3... etc` you can see from [**the grammar**](https://github.com/twitter/mysql/blob/master/sql/sql_yacc.yy#L7425) there are either ALL or DISTINCT options for the select list

Comment: @JohnRuddell I was going to edit my comment from "a bit" to "very". Marc wrote this *"it's `distinct(field1, field2, field3, ...)`"* - He should have written: it's `distinct field1, field2, field3, ...`, now that would have made more sense; least for me. I'm confused at this point. lol

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot ;) My data looks like this: 

id | name | cat1 | cat2 | cat3 | cat4
-----------------------------------------
1    test    a       b     c       d
2    test1   q       f     z       r
3    test    q       f     z       o

Comment: @BasSchreuder Thanks for? What exactly did you change/modify in your query?

Comment: @Fred-ii- but look at the first part of the comment he lays out the difference between the scope of distinct on the first column or all of them. and also look at the link I posted :) I hope that helps make more sense

Comment: @JohnRuddell All is good John, thanks. *Cheers*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65082/discussion-on-question-by-bas-schreuder-use-distinct-on-multible-rows-and-column).

Comment: Thanks a lot ;) was meant for the UK friend op here who mentioned my "thanks a bunch" can be seen as sarcastic. I have tried distinct field1, field2, field3 --  BUT  this does not work. If I distinct cat1 it works, but when I use all it does not as you can see in my code.

Comment: @BasSchreuder question. which cat column has the most distinct values?

Comment: @JohnRuddell THE "cat1" COLUMN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the long conversation in your comments lol. However what you are getting is a unique combination of all of the values in each row. if you want to remove this then you will have to do multiple selects

example case

```
create table t
(id int, 
 name varchar(55), 
 cat1  varchar(55), 
 cat2 varchar(55), 
 cat3 varchar(55), 
 cat4 varchar(55));  
INSERT INTO t values
(1, 'test', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), 
(2, 'test1', 'v', 'f', 'z', 'o'), 
(3, 'test', 'q', 'f', 'z', 'o');
```

you need to select a distinct value from each and join each column like so

```
SELECT COALESCE(t.cat1, '') as cat1, 
       COALESCE(t1.cat2, '') as cat2, 
       COALESCE(t2.cat3, '') as cat3, 
       COALESCE(t3.cat4, '') as cat4 
FROM
(   SELECT distinct cat1, @a := @a + 1 as ID_A 
    FROM t
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @a := 0) UDV_A
    GROUP BY cat1
)t
LEFT JOIN
(   SELECT distinct cat2, @b := @b + 1 as ID_B
    FROM t
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @b := 0) UDV_B
    GROUP BY cat2
) t1 ON t1.ID_B = t.ID_A
LEFT JOIN
(   SELECT distinct cat3, @c := @c + 1 as ID_C 
    FROM t
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @c := 0) UDV_C
    GROUP BY cat3
) t2 ON t2.ID_C = t.ID_A
LEFT JOIN
(   SELECT distinct cat4, @d := @d + 1 as ID_D 
    FROM t
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @d := 0) UDV_D
    GROUP BY cat4
) t3 ON t3.ID_D = t.ID_A
ORDER BY cat1 <> '' DESC, cat2 <> '' DESC, cat3 <> '' DESC, cat4 <> '' DESC;
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aed989/1)

### NOTE:

the first sub-select in the FROM() **MUST** be the column with the most distinct values or this query will fail.

Comment: Another happy ending ;)

Comment: @BasSchreuder no problem :) figured I'd let you know! btw... since **mysql_*** is deprecated (PHP's **mysql_*** api is) you should look at switching over to [**mysqli_***](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) :)

Comment: I'm sure John meant [**...with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements). @BasSchreuder ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii- you know me all too well.. probably because we've ragged on each other about it before haha

Comment: yes I found that but my php version does not accept is or something..will change this all later. BTW your answer. What is my first row with cat1 - cat4 change from a,b,c,d to other cats ? Then this does not work right ?

Comment: @BasSchreuder just change the column name inside each of the joins to be whichever one you want.. you can also join more columns if you need to... if you are having trouble setting it up correctly post in your question a more realistic data set with column names and I can set it up for you :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell you can help me ? Wow thats very generous. I can send you some links or data - how do I do this ?

Comment: @BasSchreuder tell me your email address and i'll get in touch with you